# Code to Retrieve real-time data fields in Bloomberg TRACE ABS table (without knowing ticker)

Tags: python-3.x, bloomberg

I am trying to write a code that accesses the Bloomberg 'TRACE' function, specifically to access TACT (ABS data).  The problem is, this data is live throughout the day. When a trader completes a trade, the corresponding ABS security is inputted into the system - hopefully, you see my problem.  When writing the code, I do not know the security ticker name therefore I am not able to retrieve the additional data fields in the rest of the TRACE table.

Is there a way for python to access the live security name fields in the TRACE function when they are inputted into the system?  Can python essentially open Bloomberg, input a specific function in the Bloomberg toolbar, and copy fields from the output?

I've tried other coding methods, but all seem to rely on knowing the ticker symbol.  This would require that I know ahead of time which trades are occurring before they occur.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share with us the code that you have written already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do most of what you want. I'll explain using Excel API, but everything that can be done in Excel can be done from python.

I understand you want to get a subscription to the TACT function - its securities and fields. That is not directly possible but we can do something similar in 2 steps:

1. Get a list of securities that are on TACT
2. Get the fields from TACT

1 is harder, but I think it can be done using "Fixed Income Search" - SRCH. Implement your filter by add the criteria you want to filter by. Also add "is trace disseminated". Then save the search and import the results to Excel:

```
=BSRCH("<search_name> Client","PORTFOLIO_DATA")
```

search name is the name of your saved search.

After you have the results in Excel, use formulas like

```
=BDP(A2, "TRACE_LAST_TRADE_SIZE")
```

to get fields you see in TACT function. (the formula assumes the security identifier is in cell A2)